# Flutter: Background becomes half after putting logo image

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am trying to put my image logo on the background, but my background suddenly became cropped with half of a black screen appearing. As per picture: [image]

My main.dart code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'login_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new LoginPage(),
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green
      )
    );
  }
}
```

my login_page.dart code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override  
  State createState() => new LoginPageState();
}

class LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage>{
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: new Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset('assets/arrowPNG.png'),
          ]
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/background.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

It happened after putting the image logo which is 'Image.asset('assets/arrowPNG.png'),'. How do I resolve this?

Comment: try add to Container alignment: Alignment.center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add, `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` to `Container` like this,

```
Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
                ]
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/splash_bg.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                )
            )
        )
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How do I resize the image of the center logo?

Comment: @NadiaM Do it like this ```Image.asset('assets/images/appicon.png',width: 100,height: 100,)```

Answer (score 2):

Try this below code

```
class LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage>{
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return new Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            body: new Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset('images/a_dot_ham.png'),
                    ]
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("images/background.jpg"),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }
```

When you add the below line to your Container, the issue will get resolved

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

Here is my result

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know how to position the icon at the center (the arrow in your case) so the y axis moves a bit upwards?

Comment: I didn't clearly understand your question. If you could share an example of what you want, I can help you out. Add your new questions as an edit or create a new question.